# How to Pass the Report Parameters to the Telerik Report from MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-reporting

Problem in Passing the Report Parameters to the Telerik Report from MVC?

```
typeReportSource = new TypeReportSource() { TypeName =  typeof(ADP.GRADEBOOK.Reporting.StudentProgressReport).AssemblyQualifiedName };
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "StudentIds", Value = studentValue.Remove(0, 1).ToString() });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "AssignmentHeadersCount", Value = reportDatas.AssignmentHeadersCount.ToString() });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "GradeScaleId", Value = reportDatas.GradeScaleID });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "IncludeDroppedStudents", Value = GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.IncludeDroppedStudents != null ? GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.IncludeDroppedStudents : "" });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "MarkingPeriodId", Value = MarkingPeriodeId });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "MarkingPeriodName", Value = MarkingPeriodeNm != null ? MarkingPeriodeNm : "" });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "PrintFooter", Value = GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.PrintFooter != null ? GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.PrintFooter : "" });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "ReportConnectionString", Value = (reportDatas.ReportConnectionstring != null ? ADP.GRADEBOOK.Reporting.CipherUtility.Decrypt(reportDatas.ReportConnectionstring) : "") });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "ReportHeaderName", Value = GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.ReportHeaderName != null ? GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.ReportHeaderName : "" });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "ReportId", Value = GetSpecTableDetailCompletedDatas.ReportID });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "SchoolCode", Value = (SchoolCode != null ? SchoolCode : "") });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "YearID", Value = YearId });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "SectionId", Value = SectionId });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "StaffId", Value = staffID });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "TemplateId", Value = TempID });
typeReportSource.Parameters.Add(new Parameter() { Name = "SchoolId", Value = reportDatas.SchoolID });
```

Hi, I have passed the parameter like this to the Telerik Reporting in MVC but i am getting the Exception like

> Error creating report instance (Report = ADP.GRADEBOOK.Reporting.StudentProgressReport, ADP.GRADEBOOK.Reporting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null).
>   Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all parameters.

[image: My Exception Details here]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/t_telerik_reporting_typereportsource.html

```
typeReportSource = new TypeReportSource();

typeReportSource.TypeName =                             typeof(ADP.GRADEBOOK.Reporting.StudentProgressReport).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Comment: What if I want to have few parameter to report constructor?